# How to run Python & Behave tests with some unit test framework?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-behave

I need to run my tests (written with Python and Behave) without using console. I prefer to create simple Python script and use some unit test runner. I'm thinking about unittest, but pytest and nose solutions are also welcome:) I couldn't find any hint on behave's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

behave is the "**test runner**". Use the "-o " option to store your results somewhere for whatever format(her) you want to use.

**NOTE:** 
It is basically the same like `py.test`.